# Octobercms set dynamically datepicker minDate

Tags: datepicker, field, octobercms

I need to set dynamically

```
public function filterFields($fields, $context = null)
{
   $return_date = $fields->return_date->value;
   if(empty($return_date)) {
     $fields->return_date->minDate = Carbon::now();
   }
}
```

Not work!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, may be `datetime` widget is `setting this restrictions` at `init` time and `filterfields` is **fired after that** so **it can not use new modified data**.

to over come this **we set config data before init** , we use `controller method` `formExtendFieldsBefore` add this method to your `controller`

```
public function formExtendFieldsBefore($form) {
    $form->fields['return_date']['minDate'] = \Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

it should work, please check this and if face any issue please comment.

Comment: are you adding this method in controller ? we can do teamviewer if you need extra help tomorrow

Comment: Yes, I added it on the controller!
Tomorrow afternoon, I'll call you, thank you for helping me!

Comment: Skype : hardik_satasiya

Answer (score 1):

You should pay attention to your model's `fields.yaml` - Where have you defined the `return_date` field, is it in the primary or secondary tabs ?

Try :

```
public function formExtendFieldsBefore( $widget ) {
    $widget->tabs['fields']['return_date']['minDate'] =  Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Or

```
public function formExtendFieldsBefore( $widget ) {
    $widget->secondaryTabs['fields']['return_date']['minDate'] =  Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    // notice here $widget->secondaryTabs Vs $widget->tabs
}
```

This should work, if it doesn't please share your `fields.yaml` file .