# Set minDate of field based on other field

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-widgets

I'm trying to set *minDate* of *end_at* field same as value of *start_at* field.

This is how this field are set in fields.yaml:

```
start_at:
    label: netspin.myevents::lang.modeldata.start_at
    mode: datetime
    span: left
    required: 1
    type: datepicker
    default: now
    format: d-m-Y
end_at:
    label: netspin.myevents::lang.modeldata.end_at
    mode: datetime
    span: left
    required: 1
    type: datepicker
    format: d-m-Y
```

I tried doing this way:

```
public function filterFields($fields, $context = null){
    if (!empty($fields->start_at->value)) {
        $start_date = $fields->start_at->value;
        $fields->end_at->minDate = Carbon::parse($start_date)->format('Y-m-d');
    }
}
```

I can't set *end_at* *minDate* dynamically when *start_at* is set/changed.

When i go to create page, *start_at* field as default date as *now*, so *end_at* field should have *minDate* has *now*. When start_at date is changed, *end_at* *minDate* should change to be the same as *start_at* date.

Eg:.
If *start_at* has value of 14-09-2018, *end_at* should have *minDate* 14-09-2018. If i change *start_at* value to 12-09-2018, *end_at* should have *minDate* 12-09-2018.

Update

By using *filterFields* in model I'm able to update *end_at* value . How can I also update minDate to be the same as *start_at* value?

```
public function filterFields($fields, $context = null)
{
    if (empty($this->start_at)){
        return;
    }
    if($this->start_at > $this->end_at) {
        $start_date = $this->start_at;
        $fields->end_at->value = Carbon::parse($start_date)->format('Y-m-d');
        // $fields->end_at->min_date doesn't work
        $fields->end_at->min_date = Carbon::parse($start_date)->format('Y-m-d');
    }

}
```

Comment: How actually you want to use minDate and maxDate? Can you give more details?

Comment: I've update the question with the explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627695/octobercms-set-dynamically-datepicker-mindate

Answer (score 0):

Set this to your controller

```
    public function formExtendFieldsBefore($form) 
    {
       //handle here your conditions
        $form->fields['end_at']['minDate'] = Carbon::parse($start_date)->format('Y-m-d');
    }
```

Comment: It works when I load the page. But after I change start_at date, end_at minDate doesn't change again.